# A Combinatorial Game: the Snake and the Hunter

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

*The Snake and the Hunter* is a game for two players who play in two rounds interchanging the roles of snake and hunter. The game is played in a rectangular grid of points, say $6 \times 6$. In both rounds the snake plays first and begins the game by joining with a straight line any two adjacent (either vertically or horizontally, but not diagonally) points. Thus the snake is born. From then on players take turns to lengthen the snake by one line on either of its extremes. At no stage can the snake “bite” itself. The round finishes when no further lengthening of the snake is possible, at which point the length of the snake, i.e., the number of its lines, is recorded.

In the second round players switch roles and the game proceeds in the same fashion. The winner of the game is whoever achieves the longest snake while playing the role of the snake. (The figure below shows a complete game won by the first player.)

---

[image: Snake of length]

First player's snake of length 25

[image: Snake of length]

Second player's snake of length 17

---

If both players play optimally during a given round, what is the length of the snake obtained?

Note: I originally posted this question in [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745597/a-combinatorial-game-the-snake-and-the-hunter) but received no answers.

Comment: If you "mod" this game by taking lengths modulo 2, then whoever starts the round can guarantee an optimal snake of length 1.  This is a consequence of the fact that if the underlying graph admits a perfect matching, then the first player always wins, which can be proven using the Gallai-Edmonds decomposition.  Not sure if this helps.

Comment: have you considered trying http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ Math.SE is sometimes not responsive, and you might try a site specialized for **puzzles**

Comment: I think this site is a lot more suitable for this question than puzzling.SE.

Comment: I would formulate this problem as follows.
First of all, let's forget about the second round completely.
Two players play on an $n\times n$ grid according to the above rules, and denote by $s(n)$ the length of the longest snake the first player can achieve with optimal strategies.
What do we know about $s(n)$?
Is it quadratic in $n$?
What about small values?
What about the analogous problem for other graphs than the grid?

Comment: s(2) = 3 is trivial and s(3) = 8 is easy to show.

Comment: Yeah, I also got exactly that far...

Comment: In a 3 x 4 grid the length of the longest snake the first player can achieve with optimal strategies is 11.

Comment: The first player can achieve a full length snake in the 4x4 grid too. The first player starts with down (wlog). If the second player follows with a horizontal edge (right), the first one can win in such a way that the second player from now on has only forced moves. Otherwise the first player wins by: down-down(otherwise we won)-down-right(forced)-up, and from here it is easy in both cases.

Comment: I wonder. What if the second player's response to the first player's move is a horizontal edge (right) from the upper end of the latter's move? No forced moves follow.

Comment: Equally interesting are several variants: 1. what if the snake only grows from one end? 2. what about the impartial version, i.e. a player loses if and only if there is no legal move?

Comment: @WhatsUp: your variant 2 is Slither, and was solved by William N. Anderson, Jr. here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589567490029X Your variant 1 seems to be the game called Trap here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.07485.pdf

Comment: @Zack Your second link is for the game that is the combination of Variant 1 and 2. Also, it is most commonly called as Generalized Geography (for directed graphs): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_geography#Undirected_geography

Comment: The hunter can force a direction for example playing always horizontally right up to the boundary. Doing so, he can create long borders that divide the playground into smaller parts. With this kind of stategy applied iterativelly, the snake is trapped in smaller and smaller part. Therefore,I think that for large $n \times n$ square, the longest snake is bounded by $O(n \log (n))$ and maybe $O(n)$.

Comment: @rRaphaelB4 what if the snake starts in the lower left corner? Then both players can move horizontally if they wish but it cuts off no squares. I think the best cutoff of that can be achieved is actually cutting off diagonally, which doesn’t limit the size of the snake (in terms of big-O, at least).

Comment: For $1 \times n$ it's impossible not to score $n-1$, and for $2 \times n$ there's a simple strategy to score $2n-1$: the first player starts with one of the end caps and then mirrors the second player's moves. For $3 \times n$ it already starts to get interesting. I've calculated [a table for small rectangular grids](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/946ffaa5db4f42fb8498e81826709944).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fantastic results! Should be in the OEIS.